# Tree submenu, need two independent bold on click feature

Tags: javascript, html

In my tree menu seen at http://www.wrcc.dri.edu/monitor/WWDT/index.php, is there a way to make the Variable sub menu and Region sub menu independent of eachother in terms of being bold when clicked... So for example, If I click PDSI I want that to become bold and then if I click Arizona I want that to become bold as well. I would like variable and region to both be bold when the user clicks on it. This makes it easier for the user to know what he/she clicked by just looking at the tree menu. Right now, only the active or recently clicked variable/region become bold.

You can view my source code and see that right now I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#variable').find('a').each(function () {
        if (this.href == location.href) {
            $(this).addClass('Active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('Active');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#region').find('a').each(function () {
        if (this.href == location.href) {
            $(this).addClass('Active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('Active');
        }
    });
</script>
```